# iOS Equalizer for all applications

Tags: ios, music, audio, iphone-app

I'm looking for an equalizer application for my iPhone (iOS).  Bonus points if there is an equivalent application for Android.

My key requirement is that the application provides equalization for *all* music playing apps, including the built-in `Music` app.  It doesn't matter if the app provides a built-in music player or not.

I would prefer the equalizer to have:

- Custom settings (built-in iOS equalizer doesn't have this)
- 7 or more EQ channels running the gamut from 20 - 20k Hz
- Ability to separately control overall gain along with EQ settings

My litmus test would be the ability to listen to iTunes Radio through the built-in `Music` application and use this equalizer app to adjust the sound.

Answer (score 1):

Consider [Equ](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/equ-the-quality-equalizer/id403704212?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4).

- It finely adjusts the spectral balance to get the most out of your speakers and headphones, at any playback volume.
- Save your own presets,
- This enables you to customize your preference.
- More than 1000 frequency bands Bypass mode to compare your sound EQu 
  can be used as a complete MP3 player while you open other apps.
- Retina ready

You can also try the [Audioforge Labs Equalizer](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/equalizer/id321267949?mt=8)

- Powerful parametric equalizer by moving the seven control points or
  type in the values direct.
- Select from over 10 presets or save your own. You can even share them
  via email and import presets from other people via email.

Comment: Do either of your two recommendations meet my main criteria? " `My key requirement is that the application provide equalization for all music playing apps`"